# AndroidStudio CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE is 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Tags: android-studio

I have just cloned a repository from a friend and tried to build the app on my Android Studio 3.4.2.
The APK he provided me was succeffully installed and worked just fine. But, when I'm building the apk myself on my device, I get the following errors (along with some others..):

```
A/linker: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "/system/bin/dpmd": "/system/lib64/libdpmframework.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

When running the built apk, the app actually doesn't crash or anything, just doesn't behave very well as things don't work (log in process for example). I do realize there's something wrong the the libdpmframework.so as it is built sa a **32bit lib**, but how do I 'control' it? My project gradle file is targeted to 64bit as well as my ndk compiler.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kolbeat.android.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 9
        versionName "2.5.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
```

So the question is, how can I make sure the lib will be built as 64bit?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. add `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` into **gradle.properties**
2. add new folder named **armeabi** under the libs, then copy a 32bit .so file into the new folder

Comment: It won't let me add 1# since it is deprecated. Can you explain this suggestion? Already seen it before and it was neglected as this is no longer compatible according to google.

Comment: I just wanna force the app to use the 32-bit but as you said about the issue with google, so just ignore it.
Since your app built with 64bit and it provokes the vendor lib `libdpmframework` which is compiled in 32 bit, so the issue jumps out. Im afraid there's nothing you can do in this situation.